# Multiple different images for same model with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I can't quite decide how to approach a problem.

I need to save 3x2 different images:

(Small and smallx2), (icon and iconx2), (thumb and thumbx2),

my view form you should 3 fields for uploading 3 different images:
small
icon
and thumb

I was thinking about creating 3 fields in the model for each image. Does anyone have any better ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying carrierwave, and letting the uploader do the resizing and versioning --- https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave